# Unable to display printer options with AirPrint

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-4.2, airprint

I want to add AirPrint functionality to my iPad application

I have been trying to display printer ontions described in Apple's [Drawing and Printing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html)

I have toolbar and `UIBarButtonItem *printButton`. In controller I receive `onPrintClick` and try to display printer options by such code:

```
UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
 [controller setDelegate:self];
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  [controller presentFromBarButtonItem:self.printButton animated:YES
         completionHandler:completionHandler];
 } else {
  [controller presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];
 }
```

Please help, because I do receive nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `printItem`/`printItems` property in order to use an AirPrint.

```
controller.printItem = a URL to PDF or image file;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this personally on an iPad app: [Including AirPrint on an iOS App](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/including-airprint-on-an-ios-app)